# How to get facebook app online users

Tags: php, facebook, count, fbml

I like to know if there is a way to count the users that are online at one time on an application.

They have the app installed and they are online.

I have a PHP facebook app using the FBML.

Thank you!
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take the extended permission of [user_online_presence](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) to get your desired result.
You can take this extended permission like this

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
       array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'email,user_online_presence'
        )
);
```

Comment: but why include the email permission?

Comment: Its just extra. You can exclude it. I wrote it just to tell if you want to take more than 1 permission